# GIN Web Framework (DataTable jquery plugin : Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined)

Tags: go, datatables-1.10

I have got the following Gin Web framework code where i use the dataTable jQuery plugin. My problem has to do with {{ .SliceDescription }} where i define it in my Model afterwards:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Τίτλος</th>
                <th>Περιγραφή</th>
                <th>Επισκόπηση</th>
                <th>Ενημέρωση</th>
                <th>Διαγραφή</th>
           
             </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
            {{range .todo}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ .Title }}</td>
                **<td>{{ .SliceDescription }}</td>**
                 <td><a href="/tasks/todo/{{ .ID }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm viewlink" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewModal"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>
                </td>
                <td><a href="/tasks/todo/{{ .ID }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" role="button"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></td>
                <td><a href="/tasks/todo/{{ .ID }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm  deletelink" role="button"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>                          
            </tr>
            {{end}}
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Τίτλος</th>
                <th>Περιγραφή</th>
                <th>Επισκόπηση</th>
                <th>Ενημέρωση</th>
                <th>Διαγραφή</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

with jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    
        $('#example').DataTable();
        
    });
```

and i define my database Model via GORM in GIN WEB FRAMEWORK:

```
type Todo struct {
    ID uint             `gorm:"primary_key;AUTO_INCREMENT" `
    Title string        `gorm:"not null" json:"title" `
    Description string  `gorm:"not null" json:"description" `
}

func (b Todo) SliceDescription() string {

    return string(b.Description[:45]) 
}

func (b *Todo) TableName() string {
    return "todo"
}
```

**If i place {{.Description}} instead of {{ .SliceDescription }} THERE IS NOT ANY ERROR, but if i place {{ .SliceDescription }} i get the following one:**

Unfortunately i receive the following error

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined
    at Za (jquery.dataTables.min.js:41)
    at ea (jquery.dataTables.min.js:32)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:33)
    at jquery.min.js:2
    at Function.map (jquery.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.map (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Ga (jquery.dataTables.min.js:33)
    at e (jquery.dataTables.min.js:109)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:110)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Any help would be convenient to me!

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that SliceDescription is a function.
Add SliceDescription to Todo structure as shown below.

```
type Todo struct {
    ID uint             `gorm:"primary_key;AUTO_INCREMENT" `
    Title string        `gorm:"not null" json:"title" `
    Description string  `gorm:"not null" json:"description" `
    SliceDescription string
}
```

And please insert a slice string into Todo's SliceDescription.
Then please deliver it as a template.